# How to sum area if a threshold is reached in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have a pandas data frame `df` where I try to find the sum of hectares that need to be harvested `area` before the threshold day in the other pandas data frame `lst` is reached per state.

```
lst = pd.DataFrame()
lst['ST'] = ['CA', 'MA', 'TX', 'FL', 'OH', 'WY', 'AK']
lst['doy'] = [140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200]
```

```
print(df)
            doy  ST  ...          area  left
0           111  AK  ...  4.293174e+05  760964.996900
1           120  AK  ...  4.722491e+06  760535.679500
2           121  AK  ...  8.586347e+06  760149.293900
3           122  AK  ...  2.683233e+07  758324.695200
4           122  AK  ...  2.962290e+07  758045.638900
..          ... ...  ...           ...            ...
111         211  AK  ...  7.609006e+09     107.329336
112         212  AK  ...  7.609221e+09      85.863469
113         213  AK  ...  7.609435e+09      64.397602
114         214  AK  ...  7.609650e+09      42.931735
115         215  AK  ...  7.610079e+09       0.000000
```

So I would end up with a data frame that sums up all the `area` before the threshold `doy` in `lst`

```
     area       ST
   5.0000+05      CA
   4.0123+05      MA
   3.1941+05      TX
   4.0011+05      FL
   1.2346+05      OH
   87.318+05      WY
   0.7133+05      AK
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mapping `ST` column by `Series` from `lst` and compare if less like `df['doy']` column, filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and aggregate `sum`:

```
df1 = (df[df['doy'].lt(df['ST'].map(lst.set_index('ST')['doy']))]
        .groupby('ST', as_index=False)['area'].sum()[['area','ST']])
print (df1)
         area  ST
0  70193385.4  AK
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you, you should filter the df by doy and the group by ST and sum.

Here is an example with doy before 108:

```
doy_threshold = 108
df[df['doy']<doy_threshold].groupby(by=["ST"]).sum()
```